# How to track count of Post Edits

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I want to know if there is any way to track count of Post that I edited/ suggested. I know there is total count of successful post edits at the right of User Profile Page **But** I actually want to know if there is way like as count of `flags`
[image: As this picture Show]

Helpful, declined post separated.
Actually I want to see count of `accepted-edits` , `rejected-edits` at a glace.

Comment: Isn't there a _xxxx posts edited_ link appearing above the _flags_ link on your profile view?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5055401/inzimam-tariq-it?tab=activity&sort=revisions) please. If that's not satisfying you, consider the [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)

Comment: You can find your suggestions by going to your profile, clicking the "all actions" tab, and selecting the "suggestions" sub tab. That will tell you what edits you have suggested and are pending, approved, or rejected. Clicking the status of the edit takes you to its review page. There is no easily laid out form like flags, but the information is on your profile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As I mention in question `I know there is total count of successful post edits at the right of User Profile Page` **But** `I want to see count of **accepted-edits** , **rejected-edits**` if there is any way to look.

Comment: @Kendra is not there any way to see separate count of these categories

Comment: Actually, just thought of a roundabout way to do it- Give me a moment to write up an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not an *obvious* way to see this, nor is there a way to see it on your profile, but there *is* a place on the site to see it.

Go to your profile and find the "all actions" tab:

[image: all actions]

Select the "suggestions" sub-tab:

[image: suggestions tab]

Here you'll see a list of all the edits you've suggested. Each will give you a status of "rejected", "approved", or "pending" before the name of the post you edited. These statuses are links to the corresponding edit review. Click one of these review links.

[image: edit review link]

You should see the review outcome, and at the bottom of the top box will be a "(more)" link. Click this, and you'll find at the bottom of the list your editor stats:

[image: editor stats]

These stats don't include pending suggestions, but you shouldn't ever [have more than 5 pending at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/266735) on Stack Overflow.

Alternatively, you could write an [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query for this, but that information is up to a week old.

Comment: how to query on SEDE ? I wrote `Select * from Posts where Score > 100;` to select post with score of more than 100 for example But it shows this `Something unexpected went wrong while running your query. Don't worry, blame is already being assigned.`

Comment: It's just SQL, so if you know that you should be fine. I don't know why your query didn't work. I would suggest checking out the [data-explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) tag on MSE- That's where most of the questions about it get posted. I rarely use it myself.

Comment: Actually, reading your comment again, try your query without the `;` at the end. That might be what blew it up.

Comment: Well the last comment is useful

Comment: All the things I already know except very important and that I wanted `Editor Stats` or Query

Comment: It was hard to tell from your question how much of the process you were already aware of. On the plus side, the question is detailed enough to be useful if someone else wants to find the same information later.

Comment: some edits are not counted as post edits how to determine which are to be counted and which are not?